# Memory exhausted at 1.6G even with ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')

Tags: php, symfony, memory, out-of-memory, wamp

I have an big symfony import script.
It begins by `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` but it still break around 1.6GiB.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException]
Error: Out of memory (allocated 1741422592) (tried to allocate 24 bytes)
```

I'm on Windows 10 64bit with a 32bit wamp.

Any clue ?

Comment: what is your available memory in the OS?

Comment: What is the script doing that is exhausting memory ?

Comment: you probably shouldn't be using that much memory

Comment: I cannot explain why you dont seem to have access to at least 3GB of ram, but I concur with nogad. Try breaking your one huge import into a few records per loop, gradually increase the number of records per loop and use off sets.. first loop imports records 1 - 1000, 2nd loop 1001-2000   and so on

Comment: I would bet on a loop never ending... Which fill up your memory...

Comment: Beware with timeouts of script and web server. `max_execution_time` in php

Comment: I have 16G of memory in the OS.

The script runs for about 4 hours and migrates millions of records from a data structure to another. I think the memory is exhausted by doctrine who hydrates objects, but I clean the Entity Manager from times to times.

I already proceed by batch.

Comment: The complete script should take about 2G. Why with 16G it breaks ?